# How to add to the javascript object to the same value

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have `var name = {}` and on my html page I have elements with the classes, once you click on one element it opens more elements and I want to store those IDs. However, I want to store it as a nested array. For example, click on the element(I select the class) and then opens more elements and I select different elements(I record each ID)

```
name[class]=[idOfTheElement];
```

So the question is how can I have a hierarchy like `name[class]=` and then more than one `idOfTheElement`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you share a pice of code of what you're trying to accomplish? that way it will be easier to give you a more appropriate answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add an object inside another object or array.
This will depend on what kind of structure you want

Array

```js
var name = {};
name[class]=[]; //<- for each new class you create an empty array that you can add elements to it later
name[class][0] = 'id1'; // like this
name[class][1] = 'id2';

name[class].push('id3'); // this is another way of adding elements to an array

// You will end up with a structure that looks like this
{
   className1: ['id1', 'id2' ...],
   className2: ['id3', 'id4' ...]
}
```

Object

```js
var name = {}; //<- for each new class you create an empty object that you can add properties to it later
name[class]={};

// adding properties
name[class]['id1'] = 'something';
name[class]['id2'] = 'something';

// You will end up with a structure that looks like this
{
   className1: {
     'id1': 'something',
      id2': 'something'
      ...
   },
    className2: {
     'id3': 'something',
      ...
   },
}
```

Comment: name[class][0] = 'id', so do I put [0] inside of the loop and increment each time?

Comment: It depends, if you just want to only store the `id` you can put all of them inside an array. or if you want to store something related for each `id`, you can use a object which works like a map between two things.

Comment: @Misha91191the 0 is an index you can use a variable inside a for loop. like `name[class][i]` or you can just use a method called push it automatically adds elements to the end of the array, so it would be `name[class].push(id)`